# Dynamic MySQL query in native C

Tags: mysql, c

Right now i can only use static queries for mysql select. I would like to add a variable into the select statement so i can get diffirent values depending on what the variable are containg.

```
printf("Name to search for in mysql table: ");
scanf("%s", str_to_use_in_query);

mysql_query(conn, "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM user
WHERE firstname = "text i want to add"")
```

Basicly i want to replace `text i want to add` with `str_to_use_in_query`.

Comment: Yeah thats seems like it can work very well.

Comment: Try it out for yourself